# How to pass values from one HTML page to other HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page (test.html), where i've a text box and a button. I'll enter some text in the text box and Click that button, it should open a new page (say google.com) and paste the value i entered in the previous page and automatically submit the page. I was able to achieve this in VB script which is supported in IE and not in Edge or Chrome. So is there a way we can achieve this using Javascript.

Tried, things like this, but it doesn't work.

```
    const testDiv = document.forms["actionForm"].getElementsByTagName("applicationIdentifier")
    testDiv.textContent = 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Google allows you to provide parameters in the URL.

Comment: Yeah, for Google.com, i agree with your approach. But i've some external system HTML page where they don't accept parameters in query string. So i can't pass it in the URL.

Comment: you can't do what you want in general. When you open a document in another domain, you have no access to the contents of the document.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can only run within the page it is loaded on. Also, HTTP is stateless.

If you want to interact with other pages, they will need to support the interaction by means of their code allowing you to specify their state. For GET requests, this can be done using URL parameters. To take your example, Google supports a query parameter.

https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+http

Most sites will not document this kind of thing because it is a strange way to interact. They usually expose their interactions via APIs.

> open a new page (say google.com) and paste the value i entered in the previous page and automatically submit the page

If you want to actually simulate these user actions, this cannot be done from the browser. At that point, you are describing a [WebDriver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver), for example [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [WebDriverIO](https://webdriver.io/).

It is even possible to experiment with something like [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) here, but I do not recommend it.

If by chance I am off-base and you just want a Google search bar for your site, there are ways to do that.

https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513903?hl=en

Depending on your goals, [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) might also suit your ideas. But using `<iframe>` is generally not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Ders. I was curious, if VB Script can do that trick by simply referring to document objects on other domain, why can't Javascript can do that.

Comment: "JavaScript [**in a browser**] can only run within the page it is loaded on." This is very much by design - if not, one site's JavaScript could go and steal your banking information from the next tab over! You can use the JavaScript programming language outside the browser with Node.js. Combined with WebDriverIO, that would do it. You are not running VB Script from a browser.